# $T\mapsto T*\varphi$ is a continuous map

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution

I'm doing an exercise of generalized function, which claims that
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_c^\infty\times \mathscr{D}'&\rightarrow C^\infty\\
(\varphi,T)&\mapsto T*\varphi
\end{aligned}
$$
is a continuous map of $\varphi$ and $T.$ Remember that $\mathscr{D}=C_c^\infty,$ $T*\varphi(x)=\langle T_y,\varphi(x-y)\rangle.$

I solved the case of $\varphi.$ As we have a proposition of $\mathscr{D}'$ that:
$$|\langle{T,\psi}\rangle|\le C_r\sup_{\begin{subarray}{c}
     |\alpha|\le m_r
    \end{subarray}}|\partial^\alpha \psi(x)|,\quad\forall \psi\in C_c^\infty(B_r).$$
If $\varphi_\nu\rightarrow 0,$ then we have $B_R\Subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B_R\supset \operatorname{supp}\varphi_\nu.$ Now $\forall B_k\Subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ take $r\ge k+R,$ we can prove that $$\sup_{x\in B_k}|\langle T_y,\partial^\alpha\varphi_\nu(x-y) \rangle|\rightarrow 0,\quad\forall \alpha\in \mathbb{N}^n.$$
So $T*\varphi\rightarrow 0$ in $C^\infty$ sense.

How about the case with $T$? If $T_\nu\rightarrow 0,$ $T_\nu*\varphi\rightarrow 0$ pointwise. How to say the convergence is uniform on any given $K\Subset \mathbb{R}^n?$ It's enough to prove that it's equicontinuous. If we can prove that $|T_\nu*\varphi|\le M$ uniformly, then it's solved. Is it possible to prove that?

Comment: If $T\rightarrow 0,$ do we have condition about $C_r,m_r$?

Comment: I have the same thoughts; if $T_j \to 0,$ then I believe that there, for a given compact set $K,$ are $C$ and $m$ that work for all $T_j$.

Comment: What do you know about the topology of $\mathscr{D}'$? And is $T_\nu$ supposed to be a net?

Comment: @supinf $\mathscr{D}'$ takes weak topology, to let $T_\nu\rightarrow 0\Leftrightarrow \langle{T_\nu,\varphi \rangle}\rightarrow 0,$ $\forall \varphi\in \mathscr{D}.$ I don't know more features of it. I'm not sure what "net" means here for $T_\nu.$

Comment: @DreamAR a net is a generalization. So I am guessing, with $T_\nu$ you mean a sequence of distributions (i.e. $\nu\in\Bbb N$).

Comment: Some form of uniform boundedness principle on $\mathscr{D}$ would probably be very useful here.